# I am little bit confused about pointer increment

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() {
int a = 10;
int *p = &a;
int b = 800;
double d=547;
int c=900;
printf("a = %d\n", a);
printf("p = %p\n", p);
printf("*p= %d\n", *p);

p++;
//p = &b;

printf("a = %d\n", a);
printf("p = %p\n", p);
printf("*p= %d\n", *p);
return 0;
}
```

if i print the value stored in p after increment why i'm getting 900 instead of 800?

[1]:**strong text** https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYrLA.png

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: Post your code here, don't link to external site

Comment: Your code, that should be posted and not linked, is UB. `p` points to `a` and move the pointer outside that object is _Undefined behavior_

Comment: After you increment the pointer, and then dereference it, where does it point? Nowhere it should point leading to *undefined behavior* when you dereference it.

Answer (score 2):

Besides what people have already said (undefined behavior), the reason could lie in a rearrangement of code by the compiler.

According to standard,nothing forbids the compiler to rearrange the order of code, as long as the values of the variables remain the same, it is very possible that the variables were rearranged in such a way that going one int forward from a now points to variable c.

But as this is not part of the standard, there is no way of knowing what will happen, and different compilers may return different results for this code.

Comment: And also, same compiler may return different results for this code, according its options (like optimization -O0, -O1, -O2...)